# boost::serialize segfaults

Tags: serialization, boost

For boost::serialize I am trying to define a custom class with its own serialize function, similar to http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#simplecase However, the program just segfaults. Why?

```
class Test {
        public:
        unsigned short testid;

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
        {
                ar & testid;
        }

};

int main() {
        Test mytest = {100};
        std::ofstream ofsx("test.tmp");
        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oax(ofsx);
        oax << mytest;
        cout << "Exported";
        exit(1);
}
```

I also tried the non-intrusive version with the same result.

Am I missing something?

Comment: which line causes the segfault? What does the stack trace look like?

Comment: Figured it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by linking against outdated libraries.